# Block Indent Regex

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing, block, indentation

I'm having problems about a regexp.

I'm trying to implement a regex to select just the tab indent blocks, but i cant find a way of make it work:

Example:

```
INDENT(1)
    INDENT(2)
        CONTENT(a)
        CONTENT(b)
    INDENT(3)
        CONTENT(c)
```

**So I need blocks like:**

```
INDENT(2)
    CONTENT(a)
    CONTENT(b)
```

**AND**

```
INDENT(3)
    CONTENT(c)
```

How I can do this?

---

really tks, its almost that, here is my original need:

```
table
    tr
        td
            "joao"
            "joao"
        td
            "marcos"
```

I need separated "td" blocks, could i adapt your example to that?

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on exactly what you are trying to do, but maybe something like this:

```
^(\t+)(\S.*)\n(?:\1\t.*\n)*
```

Working example: http://www.rubular.com/r/qj3WSWK9JR

The pattern searches for:

- `^(\t+)(\S.*)\n` - a line that begins with a tab (I've also captured the first line in a group, just to see the effect), followed by
- `(?:\1\t.*\n)*` - lines with more tabs.

Similarly, you can use `^( +)(\S.*)\n(?:\1 .*\n)*` for spaces ([example](http://www.rubular.com/r/7XimO7T4IZ)). Mixing spaces and tabs may be a little problematic though.

For the updated question, consider using `^(\t{2,})(\S.*)\n(?:\1\t.*\n)*`, for at least 2 tabs at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Dude, really tks, its almost that, here is my original need:
    table
        tr
            td
                "joao"
                "joao"
            td
                "marcos"
I need separated "td" blocks, could i adapt your example to that?
Really tks!

Comment: @user999472 - That is a completely different question... Why didn't you just asked what you needed? Do you need to parse the file as an HTML document? If you need to adapt my solution to your code, you just need to add another tab: `^\t(\t+)(\S.*)\n(?:\1\t.*\n)*`, or `^(\t{2,})(\S.*)\n(?:\1\t.*\n)*`.

Comment: Yes something like that its is a lexer from a precompiler project, i thought that the first example as simple to understand, but dosent match, srry about that

Comment: Thanks @Kobi the second one Was exactly what i was looking for! i will edit the original post with your solution, tks!

Comment: @user999472 - No problem, and welcome to stack overflow! There is really no need to add the solution to the question (or did you mean the answer?). If the format is exactly that, you can be more specific in your pattern, for example: `^([\t ]+td\n(?:[\t ]+"[^"]*"\n)*)`.

Comment: Tks I will add this to answer,I'm really impressed about Stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following regex to get the groups...

```
[^\s]*.*\r\n(?:\s+.*\r*\n*)*
```

this requires that your lines not begin with white space for the beginning of the blocks.

Comment: Sorry I don't know ruby to help you more