# Regex how to match indented blocks

Tags: regex, indentation

I would like to match any block of indentation up to the next line with 0 whitespace. What I tried is this: `^[^\s](\w*|\s+)` but this doesn't do what I need. My expectation is to math in a string like:

```
ajk
 sjdklj
fkldf fl kas dl  4jkl
   asdjk l    sdklj a wk
        ssdklj
4ksk adlj 2jklj
```

to have groups of matches:

Match 1

```
ajk
 sjdklj
```

Match 2

```
fkldf fl kas dl  4jkl
   asdjk l    sdklj a wk
        ssdklj
```

Match 3

```
4ksk adlj 2jklj
```

So in plain english: any block which starts with 0 whitespace (whitespaces and indentations are allowed inside the blocks).
Any helps are appreciated.

**Edit**
This `^[^\s]\w+.*` matches first lines of indented blocks, but not the indented lines themselves.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362030/block-indent-regex or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34232941/regex-to-detect-blocks-of-indented-code-not-including-the-final-newline, and https://regex101.com/r/IOKINu/1

Comment: Your example yields wrong mathces for eg: https://regex101.com/r/DucZ00/1

Comment: Last `\n` is redundant, `^(\s*)\S.*(?:\n(?:\1(?:\t|\s{4}).*)*)?`, see https://regex101.com/r/DucZ00/2

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
/(^\H.*(?:\n^\h+.*)*)/gm
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jxx5sa/2)

Or:

```
/(^\S.*(?:\n^\h+.*)*)/gm
```

If you don't want to capture leading `\n`

Answer (score 0):

Here's my Python "flavor", putting indented blocks or single lines into capture groups:

```
(?P<block>^\S.+(?:\n\s.+)*)
```

[example](https://regex101.com/r/r9gida/1)